# difference between native and increment id generator type

Tags: java, hibernate, id-generation

What is the basic difference between when we use `native` and `increment` types id generator in hibernate.

As i was having a entity, in which the generator was previuosly `native`, but then changed it to `incremental` for some time, it was working properly. But just yesterday, when i changed in to `native` again, the insertion is failing saying `Contraint Violation`.

I have index set up in the `id` field, which is auto generated.

Am i missing something here.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Native is generated by DB - if DB do it. Increment - generates by hibernate that are unique only when no other process is inserting data into the same table.